# Multi-collinearity - Intuitive Explanation

Tags: r, regression, correlation, multicollinearity

What does the **sign of the estimated co-efficient** mean in a Regression Model? (Like some are positive and some are negative)

[image: My model when I use all independent variables]

Also I understand the concept of correlation. But I fail to understand that correlation and multi-collinearity decrease the strength of the variable. Please explain intuitively.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multicollinearity, intuitively: 
The way I explain multicollinearity to my clients is, coefficients determine how much of the change to ascribe to driver A and how much to B. But, if A and B move so closely together (are correlated), the model doesn't know whether it's A or B. This isn't really a problem for prediction, since the model still gets the same estimate (choosing one or the other), but it's a problem if you want to infer anything meaningful about the strength or impact of A or B as drivers in themselves.

Comment: together they ll have impact on the model, that is why R^2 remains same. I get it, Beautifully explained! And also what does the Estimate Co-efficient determine explain with respect to magnitude and sign.